# Passing multiple arguments into a SELECT without using a complex object

Tags: ibatis, mybatis

I am trying to pass in `startSequenceId`, `stopSequenceId`, `orderNumber` into the SQL map, however, i don't wish to use a typed object, i.e. `parameterType="com.abc.Order"`, can i do so?

```
<select id="getSequenceIdByOrderNumber" parameterType="?" resultType="int">
    select *
    from log
    where seq_id
    between #{startSequenceId} and #{stopSequenceId}
    and order_no = #{orderNumber}
    and rownum = 1
</select>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@Chin I'll post what I had typed anyway with a simple example though you found what your looking for. My example using iBatis 2.3.4

```
<select id="retrieveTestXXX" parameterClass="java.util.Map" resultClass="java.lang.Integer">
    SELECT
    example_table.id
    FROM example_table
    WHERE example_table.xx_id = #testId# AND example_table.xx_id = #test2Id#
</select>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 16):

You can use the built in parameterType 'map' eg

```
Map<String, Object> parms = new HashMap<String, Object>();
parms.put("name", "abc");
parms.put("phone", "123");
parms.put("email", "123@email.com");

List<Contact> list = myBatis.selectList("getContacts",parms);


<!-- in xml mapper -->
<select id="getContacts" parameterType="map" resultMap="Contact">
  SELECT * FROM CONTACT 
  WHERE CONTACT_NAME = ${name}
  AND CONTACT_PHONE = ${phone}
  AND CONTACT_MAIl = ${email}
</select>
```

Answer (score 6):

In MyBatis 3, you can use `@Param` annotation in your mapper class(interface) method:

```
public getSequenceIdByOrderNumber(@Param("seqId") int sequenceId,@Param("orderId") int orderNo);
```

Then you can use `#{seqId}`, `#{orderId}` in the SQL without using parameterType attribute.

Comment: If you use @Param annotations, you also must add parameterType="map" to your SQL element in the mapper, or you will get a class cast exception.

Answer (score 0):

cant comment,

> Found the answer, thanks.
>
> http://code.google.com/p/mybatis/wiki/HowToSelectMultipleParams

this link is broken, currently correct one is https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-use-multiple-parameters-in-a-mapper

#### copy + paste from this wiki

> Java reflection does not provide a way to know the name of a method parameter so MyBatis names them by default like: param1, param2...
> If you want to give them a name use the @param annotation this way:

```
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Param;
public interface UserMapper {
   User selectUser(@Param("username") String username, @Param("hashedPassword") String hashedPassword);
}
```

> Now you can use them in your xml like follows:

```
<select id=”selectUser” resultType=”User”>
    select id, username, hashedPassword
    from some_table
    where username = #{username}
    and hashedPassword = #{hashedPassword}
</select>
```

#### tl;dr

when you declare method in your interface instead of standard java structure

```
Type methodName (
    ParamType1 paramName1,
    ParamType2 paramName2,
    … ); (this is interface so no method body)
```

use (add @Param)

```
Type methodName (
    @Param("name1 available in xml") ParamType1 paramName1,
    @Param("name2 available in xml") ParamType2 paramName2,
    …); (this is still interface so no method body)
```

Answer (score -2):

Found the answer, thanks.

http://code.google.com/p/mybatis/wiki/HowToSelectMultipleParams

Comment: hi dude, the link you're share was broken, can U share your Answer,.? thanks a lot -

Comment: Hi Praditha, unfortunately after the page really doesn't exist anymore after a year. Please see MalsR's answer, it is relevant.

Comment: avoid answers with just a link