# iBatis XML mapper get variable from application

Tags: .net, ibatis

I have an application in NET with iBatis and have many sql script with just one parameter. I want to expand all those with another parameter but it's almost impossible to rewrite all parameterclass. I now have this for example:

```
<select id="SelectAllByActionIdaction" resultMap="ResultSelectaction" parameterClass="int">
  select a.* from t_action a
  where a.actionid = #value#
</select>
```

This works fine, but now I want to put another variable on the query. For example like this:

```
  select a.* from t_actie a
  where a.actieid = #value#
  and a.editUserID = #getCurrentUserID#
```

The getCurrentUserID is a method which I can call everywhere in my application, how can I manage to let it work in iBatis? That wouldn't be that hard wouldn't be?

Comment: i guess you have to create an model class to combine this two value and refer to that class in `parameterClass`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible with iBatis to do such so, it's only possible to do such with parameter mapping, but since I have to many maps allready and every query needs a modification I will look for other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I found something for you here

[Passing Multiple Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9308210/passing-multiple-arguments-into-a-select-without-using-a-complex-object)

As it says you have to create a Map object and send it to iBATIS . And in query you have to use

```
parameterClass="java.util.Map"
```

iBATIS can access the value from the map using the `keys`.
In your case which will be like

```
Map<String, Object> parms = new HashMap<String, String>();
parms.put("value", "yourName");
parms.put("currentUserID", getCurrentUserID);
```

and

```
select a.* from t_actie a
where a.actieid = #value#
and a.editUserID = #currentUserID#
```

Comment: like I said it is almost impossible to rewrite all parameter maps because there are to many now, this solution I allready found, but isn't the solution I'm looking for. Looked into the documentation and it looks like it's impossible to do what I want. Seems a easy function, but to hard for iBatis.